# osx docker max connections limit

Tags: macos, sockets, docker

I installed Docker-ce(ver 17.03.1-ce-mac12 17661) on macOS Sierra(ver 10.12.5)

I created a container and run a simple socket echo server.
And then attempted to connect to the container's echo server from the host.

Initially, when the number of open sockets reached 370, a connection failure occurred,
I found the following via Google search.

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1009

To summarize, the docker for mac has its own maximum number of connections.
I modified the maximum number of connections moderately according to this content.

And I connected to the docker host in the following way.

http://pnasrat.github.io/2016/04/27/inside-docker-for-os-x-ii

I changed the ulimit configuration of the docker host as well, and changed the osx and container settings accordingly.

And again, I tried again, but this time the number of sockets exceeded the 370 limit mentioned above, but it is also blocked at about 930 ~ 940.

I try to change the settings like this, but it does not get better.

Note that a docker running on top of an Ubuntu server does not need to change any settings, and works well without any socket restrictions.

An echo server running inside the container of a docker running on Ubuntu can maintain at least 4000 sockets.

The problem only occurs with the docker for mac.

If you are aware of this situation, can anyone suggest a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? How many concurrent connections are enough, how many more cxns Ubuntu can handle than mac, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The goal is to maintain approximately 4,000 or more sockets.

The echo server that runs inside the container of the docker running on Ubuntu can maintain over 4000 sockets.

It does not work that way on the Mac.

Thanks.

Comment: I like your research, nothing else occurs to me to try. Perhaps someone else might chime in. I also love my mac but it is no linux server.

Comment: I have the same problem, although I've only tried using Docker for Mac and running into problems at ~980 connections.

Comment: I am completely new to Docker as of tonight, and I'm running into an issue where if I have 32 concurrent connections, it works fine.  If I have 33 or more, it gives me the "connection reset" error.  This also works fine when I run it locally with 100+ connections but craps out on 200 almost all the time.

Comment: Recently updated.

I guess the Docker for Mac runs on a virtual machine host, so I think it's limited for stability.
In the end, the Mac is only used for lightweight testing in a development environment, and the actual operating environment is preferably running in Ubuntu.

Comment: Could be this if you're using compose https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4486

Comment: @Cynic Thanks, but my case is tcp row socket connection, not http.